# Neo4j log level in embedded mode

Tags: logging, neo4j

In general, i have two questions:

1. Is there a way to disable logging in embedded mode? (I have a db with many deletes/writes and the log gets huge after a while)
2. Can i delete the log files without damaging the "main" database? 
   (nioneo_logical.log.v26, etc... and the lucene logs lucene.log.v13, etc...)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe my answer helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but seems like the suitable solution for passing in a config:

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put( "keep_logical_logs", "30 days" );
// Or: config.put( "keep_logical_logs", "100M size" );
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(
    "target/read-only-db/location" )
    .setConfig( config )
    .newGraphDatabase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html

Would that make your life easier? Those logs contain the transaction information and can most likely be deleted after a while. In a High Availability setup they play a bigger role as they are the main mean of transferring data between the HA cluster members.

nioneo_logical.log... files contain the transaction data for the nodes, relationships and all that, whereas lucene.log... contain the index transaction data.

Comment: Thanks for your posting Mattias! The linked resource describes a server setup. Since i am using the embedded mode, i still don't know how to configure it in code :)